# Firefox Console (Scratchpad): Persistence setInterval while Reloading the Site

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-scraping, setinterval, scratchpad

I have a very special environment where I want to scrape the content of a Web page. Due to sophisticated authentification, I can only do it in Firefox (it only works with a plugin that's only available for Firefox). I write my scraper in the console (newly 'Scratchpad') and want to log all the data to the console (and copy and save it later).

I want to iterate over the area in a synchronous way and make us setInterval. But this break when I trigger the click() event because this reloads the page. How can I fix this?

```
let xxdata = ['dfdf', 'jul', 'joh'];
let i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    // scrapes data form page
    const text = document.getElementById('AA').getElementsByClassName('BB')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;      
    const name = xxdata[i];
    document.getElementsByName('XX')[0].value = name;
    document.getElementsByName('YY')[0].click(); //reloads here
    i++;
}, 5000);
```

Any help (maybe a completely different approach) is highly approached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) and saving data to the "localStorage".